# An error from Terraria, trying to figure it out

Tags: .net, frameworks, corruption

So, my step son plays Terraria on Steam, he was playing for the past two days on one file and it has corrupted. Using my knowledge as an advantage to try and fix the corrupted file, I took a look at the error message since it's in .NET Framework.

However, I have never played Terraria in my life so some things were odd, I need a bit of help trying to diagnose the reason behind the corruption.

```
at Terraria.Main.DrawBackground()
at Terraria.Main.Draw(GameTime gameTime)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e))
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
at Microsoft.Xna.Frameworkk.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender,
EventArgs e)
   at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtrdwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Terraria.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Could you post the entire error? Or even the entire log (on pastebin)?

Comment: That was the entire error, actually.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it is hard to deduce anything from that since it just show Terraria trying to draw a frame. It doesn't even look like there is anything corrupted since it crashes on the Draw command which may be a problem with the graphics.

Comment: I'm going to test that tonight with two different video cards. I'll comment here again when I'm done with it and the result.